# AngularJS - Name of my ng-controller can't be found

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new at AngularJS, started 2 days ago, but I can't resolve this problem.

[The JS Console Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o89gR.png)

It seems that my directive ng-controller can't find my controller.

Here is my code :

```html
<section class="index" ng-app="indexApp" ng-controller="cRegister">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="username" />
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="" />
  </form>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('indexApp', [])
    app.controller('cRegister', ['$scope', function() {
      console.log('controller: true');
    }]);
  </script>
</section>
```

(This is a part of the main page, that I displayed with ng-view) :

```html
<html ng-app="web">

<head>
  <title>AngularJS, tries</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('web', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/index.php'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        })
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope someone could help me, thank you ! :D

Comment: add ng-controller in a children element of div contains ng-app attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot have two ng-app directive in one html.
remove the inner one and add that controller to the first ng-app

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But I can't let the app.controller() in the index part therefore :/

Comment: make another angular module in javascript and inject that into the index module.. but dnt use ng-app twice

Comment: Worked ! Thank you !